# Evaluate this integral with substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-fractions, substitution

Use the substitution $u=e^x$
and then partial fractions to solve
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{(e^x+1)(e^x-1)}\ dx$$

Comment: Note that if $u = e^x$, then $\mathrm{d}u = e^x\,\mathrm{d}x$, or $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}$. The rest is, as you write, merely an application of partial fractions.

Comment: note that the numerator is e^-x

Comment: Yes, so $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: Is this not a place to ask these questions? Already 2 down votes and im just trying to get help

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to show that you've already done some work on the problem.

Comment: @chessking1  When you ask a question, try to include what you have tried and where you are stuck.  Have you at least written out the integrand in terms of $u$?  If that's a challenge, the issue is with algebra, not calculus.

Comment: yea i got it in to 1 / u^2(u+1)(u-1). Which doesnt make sense beacuse they asked me to use partial fractions but i can just expan the denominator to solve it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just new on this site, I shall try to help you.

$$I=\int\frac{e^{-x}}{(e^x+1)(e^x-1)}\, dx=\int\frac{dx}{e^x(e^x+1)(e^x-1)}\, dx$$ Change variable $$e^x=t\implies x=\log(t)\implies dx=\frac{dt}t$$ So, $$I=\int \frac{dt}{t^2(t+1)(t-1)}$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{1}{t^2(t+1)(t-1)}=-\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{2 (t+1)}+\frac{1}{2 (t-1)}$$ Integration of each term $$I=\frac 1t-\frac12\log(t+1)+\frac12\log(t-1)=\frac 1t+\frac12\log\frac{t-1}{t+1}$$ If you want, go back to $x$ $$I=e^{-x}+\frac12\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right)$$ You are certainly able to recognize the last term to be a well know hyperbolic function.

Now, your turn !